# doxygen: output callgraph files naming

Tags: c++, doxygen, graphviz, dot

I'm using doxygen with the following configure settings:

```
HAVE_DOT               = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
```

There are not any additional doxygen settings in the source files.

As an output I get .dot files which names look like temporary(or encrypted) e.g.:

```
file1_8cpp_a45da2e999b9e1b551e98de93487bd552_cgraph.dot
file1_8cpp_a45da2e999b9e1b551e98de93487bd552_cgraph.md5
file2_8cpp_a45da2e999b9e1b551e98de93487bd552_icgraph.dot
file2_8cpp_a45da2e999b9e1b551e98de93487bd552_icgraph.md5
```

where each dot file corresponds to a separate function in cpp file and its dependencies.

Is there any way to establish naming of these files according to function names of what they represent?

Furthermore, in the corresponding file1_8cpp.html graph representations (or link to them) for each function are missing. Instead there is: "Here is the call graph for this function: Here is the caller graph for this function: "

What can be the reason?

Comment: for the missing graphs, did you specify where the DOT program resides in the config file?

Comment: It was specified incorrectly. Correcting the path, hasn't helped, though,

Comment: Are you getting any warnings reported? (Have you disabled them?)